# GNU screen: window in multiple sessions

Tags: gnu-screen

Recently, I came across the following situation: I am using multiple screen sessions. Sometimes, it happens that a window of one screen session shows up in another screen session. Whatever I do in this window will also affect the other session. When closing that window, it will be closed in the other session as well. However, I did not intended to use the same window in multiple unrelated sessions and I also don't know how I produced this situation.

How is it possible that one window appears in more than one session? And how can I remove that window from one of the sessions without closing the window?

Comment: How are you opening the window? Are you specifying the session to open it in? Or are you just using the keybinding?

Comment: I use `screen -rx` to attach to a screen and the usual keybindings (`^A` `C`, `^A`, `D`) to create new window or detach from a screen. However. Sometimes, I hit adjacent keys or wrong keys and end up in the described situation. My question is basically about how can you make one window appear in more than one session?

Comment: Are you sure that they're different screen sessions? Using the `-x` argument means you can attach to a un-detached screen session, meaning you may just be viewing the same session in multiple places instead of different sessions. I only ask because I just scanned through the screen man looking at every occurrence of the word "session" and "window" and didn't see any way to open a window across multiple sessions. I did see one reference to "shared" window, but it looks like it's referring to it being attached more than once. (My screen may have been compiled without certain functionality, tho)

Comment: Me neither. That's why I asked this question. But I'm pretty sure those were different sessions because the windows in the session were different except for the last one.

Comment: Normally, when I try to attach to a screen from within a screen, I get an error that this is impossible. However, I just ran into a situation where that is actually possible...